# How to display overlay containing spatial distribution of something on Google Maps (and do it fast)

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

## Question

I want to display overlay containing spatial distribution of something on Google Map.

Here are results of my approach, and I want something similar:

[image: Results of current approach]

For now I display about 10 000 instances [maps.google.Rectangle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Rectangle), each is about 2km x 2km wide. This approach is quite slow (this map is rendered for couple of seconds).

Is there any way to render this faster? Best solutions would use javascript only (but I guess I could generate some KML on the fly).

## Setup

1. I'm doing some prototyping work, so I don't use full blown server (any server altogether) but just ipython.org/notebook.html, that means that I can very easily call any python function, but there is no easy way to say path `/path/` will output following KML. On the other hand everything is on my computer so `file://` urls would work
2. Backend is written in python.

## What I have tried

1. Outputting polygons (it is slow)
2. Using heatmaps. I had problems with scaling, basically when zoomed out it looks like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJqgq.jpg, and when scaled in it looks like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmcC6.jpg.

Comment: Or maybe a [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesLayer)

Comment: I'll definitely try a heatmap. As for FusionTable, google documentation states that data from FusionTables can't be easily modified on the fly, and my data will is and will be autogenerated.

Comment: That wasn't obvious. Just trying to see if you can use one of the "Layers" (FusionTablesLayer or KmlLayer) for faster rendering.  You might be able to create tiles on your server to overlay on the map (but that is more work).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to use KML next, but before I'll need to check if I can use `file://` urls in KMLLayer.

Answer (score 0):

You can download my class hilbert curve from phpclasses.org. It uses a space filling curve to subdivide the plane and reduce the dimension.